Addin not loading for shared mailbox after email address change
The addin is not loading for a mailbox after the email address is changed. We tried restarting outlook desktop app and also restarting the addin but no use.
It remains in the state shown in image1.
However, the issue is resolved as soon as we create a new outlook profile.
The addin loads fine for the mailbox as shown in image2.
This issue is only happening for outlook desktop app.
Expected behavior is after some time to sync up, the addin loads for the mailbox.
Current behavior is the addin only loads after creating a new profile
To reproduce the issue:

Change the email and username of a shared mailbox that the user has delegate access to.
Once the changes sync up (give it 10 mins), try and open the addin.
The addin will not load
Create a new outlook profile for the same user
Once the shared mailbox shows up in the profile, the addin will start working.



